# pass value to main thread from child thread using promise and future

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I was trying to send data from the main thread to child thread in an asynchronous manner using future and promise. Here is the code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int sampleFunc(vector<future<int>> &f) {

    int a = f[0].get();
    cout <<"got a from promise 1" << endl;

    int b = f[1].get();
    cout <<"got b from promise 2" << endl;

    return a + b;
}
int main() {
    int outputVal;
    int k = 2;
    std::vector<promise<int>> p(k);
    vector<future<int>> f(k);

    f[0] = p[0].get_future();
    f[1] = p[1].get_future();

    std::future<int> fu = std::async(std::launch::async,sampleFunc,std::ref(f));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    p[0].set_value(2);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));

    p[1].set_value(4);

    outputVal = fu.get();

    cout << outputVal << endl;
}
```

The delays might have some other meaning, for example, the values of `a` and `b` might not be ready yet( probably we are waiting for some other task to happen inside the main thread).

That, being said, how to pass partial data (asynchronously, like above example) from the child thread to the main thread?. Can this model of data transfer be extended to other threads (child thread to another child thread)?

Thanks !

Comment: All threads in a process are peers. Threads don't have parent/child relationships.

Comment: Yes, I want to mean, peer to peer thread communication by the line `child thread to another child thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "classical solution" to share data between threads: `shared_ptr`. I do not think that `promise` and `future` can be (normally) used to transfer partial data: "Note that the std::promise object is meant to be used only once." (cppreference.com: [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise)).
I modified your code (a little bit) to show my point, please come back if there are troubles:

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

//  only a string, but a structure is more general
struct Transfer {
    std::string m_status;

    Transfer() noexcept {};
    Transfer(const std::string& status) : m_status(status)
    {};
};

// std::atomic_shared_ptr is a (new) alternative to this use of std::shared_ptr

//  warning: atomic functions for shared pointers do work on the shared 
//      pointer, not on the contained data 
int sampleFunc(vector<future<int>> &f, std::shared_ptr<Transfer>& status) {

    std::atomic_store(&status, std::make_shared<Transfer>("Waiting for the first result ..."));

    int a = f[0].get();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100)); // to "sync" the output
    cout << "got a from promise 1" << endl;

    std::atomic_store(&status, std::make_shared<Transfer>("Waiting for the second result ..."));

    int b = f[1].get();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));  //to "sync" the output
    cout << "got b from promise 2" << endl;

    std::atomic_store(&status, std::make_shared<Transfer>("Finishing ..."));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int outputVal;
    int k = 2;
    std::vector<promise<int>> p(k);
    vector<future<int>> f(k);

    f[0] = p[0].get_future();
    f[1] = p[1].get_future();

    std::shared_ptr<Transfer> status_shared = std::make_shared<Transfer>("Started");
    //  do not forget to use std::ref
    std::future<int> fu = std::async(std::launch::async, sampleFunc, std::ref(f), std::ref(status_shared));

    const auto wait_for_1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [](promise<int>& p) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        p.set_value(2);
    }, std::ref(p[0]));

    const auto wait_for_2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [](promise<int>& p) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));
        p.set_value(4);
    }, std::ref(p[1]));

    do {
        const auto status = std::atomic_load(&status_shared);
        cout << status->m_status << '\n';
    } while (future_status::timeout == fu.wait_for(chrono::seconds(1)));

    outputVal = fu.get();

    cout << outputVal << endl;

    return 0;
}
```